# How do I style/remove content between quotes inside an <a> tag (CSS/JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this login form which is generated dynamically. When selecting the 'Forgot Password' option, a new 'Back to Login' message appears with a line '|' after it. I need to remove this line but I can't work out how to select it because of where it is displayed.

The parent container has the class `.upme-back-to-login` inside that is an `<a>` tag and then after the closing tag `</a>` there are a set of quote marks which contain the line; see this screenshot of console:

[image: IMG01]

My question is **how do I remove or hide only the content in the quotes using either CSS *or JS***?

Comment: Can you post your code along with this.

Comment: You can add a snippet in your post to copy your code and make it workable so people here can help you, instead of a screenshot.

Comment: I would suggest not putting the pipe character in there in the first place...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I have no control over what is rendered initially - "I have this login form which is generated dynamically."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this

```
.upme-back-to-login {
  font-size:0;
}
.upme-back-to-login a {
  font-size:16px;
}
```

That's gonna set font-size to 0 on the parent div and hide that pipe but it might affect link size as well that's why I added font-size for link

Comment: It's working! Thanks, will mark as correct answer when I can :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
.upme-back-to-login {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.upme-back-to-login > * {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

It will make the unwanted content invisible and unselectable, as if it was not there at all, but otherwise won't change anything in the layout (you would still be able to use inherited font size for nested elements etc.)